# Struggling to understand derivative

Tags: calculus

I was looking at this solution for $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac1x$
$$\require{cancel}\frac d{dx}\frac1x=\frac dd\frac1{x^2}=\frac{\cancel d}{\cancel d}\frac1{x^2}=-\frac1{x^2}$$
I guess it makes sense, there is nothing tricky there, but it doesn't seem to match up with my online calculator (wolfram alpha) when I tried $\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{dx}{dx}$, which gave me $1$, which was inconsistent with my answer of $-1$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a howler to cancel the d's - a folk solution that is formally incorrect. The online calculator you used is also wrong.

Comment: Is $\dfrac{sin \:x}{n}=six=6?$ You are proceeding in the same way.

Comment: wait so the d/dx is an operator not a literal fraction? @ParclyTaxel

Comment: This has to be a joke.

Comment: My question, or the solution? I'm genuinely confused. @MathematicsStudent1122

Comment: The "solution" you have quoted is a joke.

Comment: @BarryChau Joke or whatever, but the end of your "*question*" $\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{dx}{dx}$ has nothing to do with the picture inserted above it.

Comment: but what they did was multiplying the fraction @dxiv

Comment: @BarryChau Did you even *look* at that pic? Wrong as it is, but it's allegedly about $\frac{d}{dx} \color{red}{\frac{1}{x}}\,$ ***not*** $\,\frac{d}{dx} \color{red}{x}\,$. Sorry, not sure at this point whether you are confused or just trolling.

Comment: WLOG let $x=\sin^{-1}(6n)$ @mfl

Comment: sorry, i just multiplied together the fractions because they transferred the $x$ from the $dx$ in the denominator to 1/x so I just assumed that they were meaning to multiply and eventually cancel out the d/d @dxiv but now i don't understand the presence of d/dx

Comment: This is not the way to begin to understand derivatives - it is the rough mathematical equivalent of a pun: the operations you are carrying out depend on the possibility of an alternative interpretation of the symbols involved (including the line marking a fraction turning into a minus sign). Someone has had a bit of fun with it.

Comment: But even if you could cancel the $d$ in a parallel universe, why would it leave a negative sign?

Comment: @SahibaArora The horizontal line from the fraction >.<

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Oh my god. My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: *Why the Leibniz notation must be abolished*, episode DCLXVI.

Comment: StackExchange really needs a "Haha" reaction...

Comment: I wonder if the OP thinks that  $$\frac1 1 =\frac {\cancel 1}{\cancel 1}=-1. $$

Comment: i also wonder @MartinArgerami

Comment: @MartinArgerami: No, it's just $$\frac{1}{1} = -$$ :-)

Comment: What a funny troll.

Comment: he seemed genuinely confused @md2perpe

Answer (score 3):

$1/x^2$ is NOT the derivative of $1/x$. Probably, you asked to the online calculator (any link?) to evaluate the fraction 
$$\frac{d}{d\cdot x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
where $d$ and $x$ are non zero numbers.
Try this [link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%5Cright)).

P.S. This is a correct computation of the derivative of $1/x$ at $x\not=0$:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x-(x+h)}{x(x+h)h} =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{x(x+h)}=- \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: but isn't the derivative of 1/x -1/x^2

Comment: @Barry Chau Yes, that is also the answer you will find by clicking the link I gave you above.

Comment: And suddenly it all makes sense.... (+1) for the forensic insight into the mind of the calculus newbie.

Answer (score 2):

OP, as the comments here have indicated, this isn't valid mathematics - it bears no resemblance to the actual process of differentiation. (Cancel the D's? Yeah, every grumbling high school student wishes. Cancel the F's too....)

What we *actually* do is the following: in the definition of the derivative, which says $\frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$, we substitute our particular function, $\frac{1}{x}$, wherever $f$ appears: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h}.$$ (Notice how changing $f(x)$ to $\frac{1}{x}$ means we change $f(x + h)$ to $\frac{1}{x+h}$.)

Now, $$\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x}{x(x+h)} - \frac{x+h}{x(x+h)} = \frac{-h}{x(x+h)}.$$ So we go ahead and plug that right in!

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{x(x+h)}$$

after we cancel the $h$'s. But as $h \to 0$, $x\cdot(x+h) \to x\cdot (x) = x^2$, so that means

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{x(x+h)} = \frac{-1}{x^2}.$$

And *that's* how you do it!

Comment: There is a $-$ missing.

Comment: @SahibaArora nuts - thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the derivative.
The derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ for all $x \ne -1$.

Answer (score 1):

That is... very wrong. Wherever you found that image is somewhere you shouldn't consult for your future mathematics endeavors.

When it comes to derivatives, there's something called the *power rule*, explicitly, it's this following rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

So in your case above of $\frac{1}{x}$, note it's equivalent to $x^{-1}$. Thus we have $n=-1$ and using the above rule we get:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{-1}=(-1)x^{-2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
which is the proper way of getting the result.

**EDIT:** In your attempt of $\frac{d}{dx} x$ (which was good that you tried to see the error!) we would again follow the power rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} x^1 = (1)x^{1-1}=(1)x^0=1.$$